# what is the difference between "XYZ-based company" and "XYZ company"

Tags: grammar, american-english, business-language

## Question(s)

- In the following paragraph, if i change **Abbott Park, Illinois-based company** to **Abbott Park, Illinois company** will the meaning change?
- Is there a technical term for **-based** ?
- When do we use such terms in english?
- I think it's called **within-word dashes**

## Paragraph

Abbott Labs manufactures and develops a wide range of pharmaceuticals,
nutrition supplements, and personal care products. Shares in the
**Abbott Park, Illinois-based company** rose 1 in trading today to close
at 64 1/8.

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

-based implies that the place is a base for operations that take place across a wider region. In Abbott's case worldwide. Without -based, there is a possibility that Abbott Park is the only place the company impacts. For example, one would not generally say of a mom and pop sandwich shop that it is -based. But a company whose agents operate far and wide and report back the the base or headquarters, deserves a -based.

If you take -based away, the meaning will not really change, but ambiguity with respect to region of impact will be possibly introduced.

With some place names being used in company names, -based resolves ambiguity between name and location.

The technical term is "headquartered in".